# Can I bring a new coffee maker and several small sealed bags of coffee to India from the USA?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, india, international-travel, food-and-drink

Can I bring a new, small sized coffee maker and several small bags of coffee, with me to India? In my checked luggage of course.

Comment: From experience I'll say that it should be fine. Indian immigration is not strict as long as they are packaged goods.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can bring the coffee maker and coffee. provided they are within your import limit of 
Rs.35000.

You may please refer the link for further details. http://www.cbec.gov.in/trvler-guide_ason22may2013.pdf